# Uso correcto de UNION y ORDER BY

Tags: sql

Me podrían ayudar con estas consultas sql que me generan problemas por favor

Estoy insertando registros en una tabla de una BD y tengo que ordenar los registros por fecha
DESC y tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT * FROM viaje ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

pero ahora con la fecha DESC de la tabla viaje tengo que actualizar otra tabla (registro) que cuenta con el mismo campo (fecha)

```
UPDATE registro AS r INNER JOIN viaje AS v ON r.ID = v.ID SET r.fecha = v.fecha WHERE r.ID = v.ID
```

actualmente cuento con la siguiente consulta, funciona a la perfección pero el problema es que tarda un poco en hacer los cambios

```
UPDATE registro AS r SET r.fecha = (SELECT fecha FROM viajes WHERE r.ID = ID ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1)
```

y me sugirieron que primero ordenara por fecha DESC y después actualizara (Lo que quiero hacer en las primeras dos consulta anteriores)

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Si funciona y tarda en hacer los cambios, es porque ya empiezas a tener bastantes registros y aún no has creado un índice para la `fecha`. Sólo tienes que ejecutar esta instrucción, y notarás un gran cambio a partir de ahora:

```
ALTER TABLE viaje ADD INDEX(fecha);
```

Sí aún va lento, crea otro índice en la tabla `registro`.

Los índices ocupan espacio, pero almacenan una versión ordenada de la tabla. Desde que lo crees, los `ORDER BY fecha` serán inmediatos.

Comment: Hola @David asi es mi BD ya cuenta con alrededor de 20,000 registros, Gracias, lo intento y regreso por cualquier duda

Comment: El segundo update no tiene where.. lo esta haciendo siempre sobre toda la tabla.. por eso le anda lento ;)

Comment: @gbianchi podrias aclarame un poco más por favor.

Comment: @gbianchi se refiere a que, si no pones un WHERE en el UPDATE, estás modificando los 20.000 registros de tu tabla. Es mejor focalizarte en el subconjunto que quieras modificar.